# chdir() in C++ Getting Errors

Tags: c++, cd, chdir

I am trying to run a minimal terminal shell program through a socket on a unix machine. When I use `system("cd directory")` it doesn't work. So I did a bit of research and came across `chdir()`, which looked like it would work. When I tried it, though, it gave me errors every single time. Here is my code:

```
if (chdir(argument) < 0) {
     send(sock, "[*] Directory does not exits!\n", strlen("[*] Directory does not exits!\n"), 0);
}
else {
    string argumentString(argument);
    string entireMessage = "[*] New working directory: " + argumentString;
    char entireMessageChar[64];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; entireMessage[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        entireMessageChar[i] = entireMessage[i];
    }
    send(sock, &entireMessage, strlen(entireMessageChar), 0);
}
```

Could anyone please tell me why `chdir()` isn't changing directories?
Thanks.

Comment: It's not possible to tell without knowing _exactly_ what the return code of `chdir()` is. You can't just throw it away after checking whether it's nonzero, so right now, this question doesn't contain enough information to allow a useful answer.

Comment: Okay hold on I will get the code.

Comment: By the way -- the reason `system("cd directory")` doesn't work is that `system()` starts a shell; the shell changes to the new directory, and then the shell exits. That you started a child process that changed its directory doesn't mean _your_ directory changes.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy it returns NULL i think. It shows ? in the console.

Comment: Use `perror()` or `strerror()`.

Comment: Oh my bad it returned 1 when I did cd ..

Comment: Why the -1's from people? Could you explain why you took a point off?

Comment: The -1s probably stem from not having researched the problem adequately before asking the question. `chdir()` has documentation, and we've told you absolutely nothing which isn't found in it. If you'd shown evidence of making a reasonable effort to debug the issue yourself, things would probably be better-received. (Not trimming the code to the minimum necessary, showing your exact inputs, etc. also contribute).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of `errno` after `chdir()` has exited needs to be checked to determine why it doesn't work.

Likely exit status values include:

- EACCESS (no permission for the target)
- ENOENT (file does not exist)
- ENOTDIR (target is a file, not a directory).

Check the documentation for your operating system's implementation for a complete list.

Comment: Assuming a POSIX-compliant `chdir`, it returns 0 on success and -1 on failure. If it fails, it sets `errno` to one of those values. And you should set `errno` to 0 before the call.

Comment: @KeithThompson Quite right. That's what I get for trying to answer C questions after a decade elsewhere...

Comment: Sorry if I'm confusing anyone by my comments. Errno returns 2

Comment: @InsertNameHere 2 would be ENOENT -- so you're asking it to cd to a directory that doesn't exist.

Comment: But if I do cd .., it doesn't work, and that should take me to my parent directory. Right?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy when I type cd /Applications, it should take me to the applications folder. I am running OSX 10.8 if that is any help

Comment: @InsertNameHere What *exactly* are you passing to `chdir`?

Comment: I just realized that at the end of my array was a `\n` so that's why it wasn't working